# Defining Spring Beans with same method name for different profiles

Tags: java, spring

I have a configuration class defining two beans depending on the selected profile, with overridden configuration methods:

```
@Configuration
class MyConfig {
    @Profile("profile")
    @Bean
    MyBean myBean(MyBeanProperties properties) {
        return new MyBean(properties);
    }

    @Profile("!profile")
    @Bean
    MyBean myBean(MyBeanProperties properties, AdditionalProperties addProps) {
        MyBean result = new MyBean(properties);
        result.addAdditionalProperties(addProps);
        return result;
    }
}
```

and a class which autowires the `MyBean` into it

```
@Service
class MyService {
     MyBean autowiredBean;
     private MyService(MyBean bean) { this.autowiredBean = bean; }
}
```

Now, when I start the Spring context, it fails with the message

> Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.MyServce required a bean of type 'com.example.MyBean' that could not be found.

How is that possible? I clearly define the Spring bean so it should be present when the context is created.

Comment: You can create two different configuration file and specify the profiles on class level. Example available in github https://github.com/naveenkulkarni029/categories-api `@Profile` applied to Controller level as an example

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason for this is that Spring considers these beans to be of the same name because of the configuration method name, so it fails to instantiate them (although only one should be created in any given active Profile). This will work fine:

```
@Configuration
class MyConfig {
    @Profile("profile")
    @Bean
    MyBean myBean(MyBeanProperties properties) {
        return new MyBean(properties);
    }

    @Profile("!profile")
    @Bean
    // note different method name
    MyBean otherBean(MyBeanProperties properties, AdditionalProperties addProps) {
        MyBean result = new MyBean(properties);
        result.addAdditionalProperties(addProps);
        return result;
    }
}
```

I have not found this behavior explained anywhere so I posted this self-answered question to share.

The real-life case this occurred for me what a `WebClient` which was instantiated with a client registration in one profile, and without one in the other (because none was needed for creating an exchange filter).

Comment: Had exactly the same problem, thanks very much. This is really weird behaviour and perhaps not documented and not logged as a warning by spring. It looks like if more than one method of same type have the same name (irrespective to number/type of args), spring ignore those @beans.

Answer (score 6):

This is caused when two beans are defined with the same method name and one of them is expected to be skipped based on some condition(in this case based on profile). In this case, "myBean" is defined twice with different profiles.

The way a config class gets parsed is by iterating through all the beanMethods in that class and adding the corresponding bean definition. The iteration is in order of how the beanMethods are defined in the config class. [Here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/fae484855b0d6429b7cbfc0929bfa4e19c3b0fec/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java#L152) is the link to the code.

Depending on the order in which these beans are defined in the config class, if the first bean defined is expected to be skipped based on the profile annotation, the beanMethod name gets added to a list of "to-be-skipped" beanMethods. [Here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/fae484855b0d6429b7cbfc0929bfa4e19c3b0fec/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java#L193) is the link to the code.

Now, when it encounters the second bean with the same name, it sees that this beanMethod name is already present in the "to-be-skipped" methods list and hence skips the bean even though there is no inherent condition (like the profile) that would cause it to be skipped. [Here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/fae484855b0d6429b7cbfc0929bfa4e19c3b0fec/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java#L197) is the link to the code.

You will notice that if you swap the order of the beans and use the same profile to run which was failing earlier, the bean would get picked up.

Using unique beanMethod names within the config class would be the best way to avoid this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I figured why changing the names of method allowed application context to load:

The problem is, spring container requires all it's beans to have a unique name as descried here https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-beanname

> Every bean has one or more identifiers. These identifiers must be unique within the container that hosts the bean.

When not using XML configuration, I think the only way to have same bean method name is to give a unique name to beans within the `@Bean(NAME)` annotation, see this for details [Spring bean with same method name but different qualifier fail to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54727131/spring-bean-with-same-method-name-but-different-qualifier-fail-to-load)

Comment: Yes, but the question is why Spring tries to create both beans to begin with, considering one is not in the active profile.

Comment: i think it happens during inspection and not actual class loading, if inspection fails it ignores those bean(s)