# Spring boot - multiple RestTemplate implementations based on Spring profile

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I'm trying to load different `RestTemplate`s for different profiles. One of the rest template config is available inside a jar that is used in the project. Here is how I implemented it:

**RestTemplateProviderConfiguration.java**

```java
package com.my.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import static org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase;

@Configuration
public class RestTemplateProviderConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    @Value("${spring.profiles.active:}")
    private String activeProfile;

    @Value("${iam.rest.template:}")
    private String iamRestTemplateQualifier;

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return equalsIgnoreCase(activeProfile, "local") ? new RestTemplate() : (RestTemplate) appContext.getBean(iamRestTemplateQualifier);
    }
}
```

**Service.java**

```java
...
@Autowired
private RestTemplateProviderConfiguration restTemplateProviderConfiguration;
...

public void testRestClient() {
    return restTemplateProviderConfiguration.restTemplate()
                    .exchange(...);
}
```

Can anyone suggest a better method where I can just use:

```java
@Autowire
RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

and it will load the correct template based on the active spring profile?

Solution #1 (doesn't work):
I've created two beans and have loaded them conditionally based on active profile. However, it does not load the template that's available in jar for non-local profile:

```
@Bean
@Profile("local")
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}

@Bean
@Profile("!local")
public RestTemplate iamrestTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have 2 different `@Configuration`, for each profile with equivalent profile as  `@Profile({"local"})`

Each configuration will return different implementation of `RestTemplate` (and other relevant beans)

You can also define [Profile per Bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59406908/defining-spring-beans-with-same-method-name-for-different-profiles), but it could be confusing

> ```
> @Profile("profile")
> @Bean
> MyBean myBean(MyBeanProperties properties) {
> ```

Comment: Can you elaborate how I can do that? If i just place the @Profile over the existing configuration, what will happen if i run the project in a different profile and call the rest template methods? Will it automatically call the default rest template?

Comment: @saran3h if profile is local it will load the local profile configuration, and on prod it won't be loaded, but the configuration marked as prod

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Spring 5.1.4+, you can specify `@Profile` annotation for your `RestTemplate` beans.

```
@Bean
@Profile("local")
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}

@Bean
@Profile("!local")
public RestTemplate iamrestTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}
```

See [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) for this annotation.

Comment: This looks pretty good. And how should i access this in service? Using @Autowired RestTemplate restTemplate;?

Comment: @saran3h Yes, Spring will load the RestTemplate-bean by its className. Only if there is another (a third ) RestTemplate involved you can get a conflict. In that case, you could simply name your 2 RestTemplate-beans `@Bean(name="iamrestTemplate")` and use `@Qualifier("iamrestTemplate")` where you want to use your profile-based RestTemplate.

Comment: @Pavel This doesn't work as one of the implementation of RestTemplate is coming from a jar.A point that i forgot to mention in the question.