# Spring @Bean with different name but same method name throws Bean creation exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, javabeans

New to spring.
I have defined 2 @Beans with unique names for each but with the same method name. One of the beans are not created and No valid bean exception is thrown.

```
@Bean("Example.A") 
public ClassA getNewBean() {
   return new ClassA();
}




@Bean("Example.B")
public ClassA getNewBean() {
  return new ClassA();
}
```

The second Bean is not created and Exception is thrown as no valid bean exists ClassA.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54727131/spring-bean-with-same-method-name-but-different-qualifier-fail-to-load) has the two beans in different classes, whereas in my case both are within the same @Configuration.

Comment: One `class` cannot have multiple same name methods. Can you show your code and stack trace?

Comment: Can you provide stacktrace? How you inject these beans?

Answer (score 1):

When you inject by [bean name](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.3/reference/html/core.html#beans-java-customizing-bean-naming), you can use [`@Resource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.3/reference/html/core.html#beans-resource-annotation):

```java
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @Resource(name = "Example.A")
    private ClassA obj;

    // ...
}
```

As an aside, beans should be named by [Java standard convention](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.3/reference/html/core.html#beans-beanname).